# Multiple very small, very low visibility moving stars?

Tags: amateur-observing

I've been seeing these very small star like objects cross the sky for a couple months now. I notice that I see the them in clusters, for instance I see 2 one day and then another the next, and then I don't see any for another month or so. I assumed it was the space station until I saw another moving behind the first one I saw, and it was moving in the same general direct but clearly at a different angle. Just tonight I was Watching two as usual for about 10 seconds until one just zips around like a shooting star? Assuming it was a shooting star but I have my doubts.

Comment: Stars don’t ‘zip around’ to the human eyes. Probably a meteor / plane / satellite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow moving star like objects in the night sky](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32969/slow-moving-star-like-objects-in-the-night-sky)