# more than 30 moving stars

Tags: star

I am Abdul Kadhir from Kochi, Kerala, India. I, my wife and my daughter have seen today (2020-01-11) morning 5.45 AM IST a line of stars. A pair of more than 30 stars moving in a line from south to north. In between one pair stars, there was a little distance and in between 2 pair the distance is 3 times. Roughly so: `* *      * *     * *`.

It was a wonderful experience. Single stars of about 20 came with in the same line with a little time gap... I want to ask, is this normally happening in the sky, or what is going on?

Every morning, when I wake up, I will look up the sky and after watching.

Comment: Could it be Starlink satellite train? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32034/10813

Comment: Is this normally happening? "Thanks" to El\*n M\*sk it is now. There was a new batch of orbital vermin launched on Jan 6.

Comment: @abdulkadhir it's likely that you saw the fourth batch of sixty [Starlink satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink_(satellite_constellation)#List_of_launches) just recently launched. They start out together then spread out over time. You can read about them everywhere in the internet, and in [several other posts here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=starlink) and in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starlink). Each group stars together then spreads out into a line and eventually spread out evenly along their own circular orbit.

Comment: Also see the article and videos in https://www.space.com/spacex-starlink-2-satellites-night-sky-visibility.html I can't find TLEs for this batch yet so I can't propagate them to see for sure if they are what you saw, but it's hard to imagine that it could be anything else!