# I also see the line of 30 stars @today(11/jan/2020)on5:35am

Tags: star

I can't take any pic because I don't know how many light are coming.

Comment: There have been a large number of questions here about seeing Starlink satellites. If you have good reason to believe your sighting was *not* of Starlink, please add this to the question or it will almost certainly be closed as a duplicate, like all the others.

Comment: @antispinwards New users will never know about "all the others" so we can't hold it against them. Hopefully if the rate significantly increases [something like you suggested.](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/545/7982) can be figured out

Comment: Hi @DasD'Cruz, welcome to Stack Exchange! Congratulations for (most likely) seeing a newly deployed group of Starlink satellites! You may find the comments I left [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34671/7982) interesting and/or helpful.