# Various stars moving in a line

Tags: observable-universe

I from India saw various stars moving in a line from North-West direction to the South-East direction at 5:27 AM on date 13 february 2020... They all are moving rapidly and can be easily seen from the earth's surface.... Wat was it? Any idea? Any one?

Comment: Starlink satellites. Read more here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following