# Fast moving lights moving west to east

Tags: satellite

at approximately 5:45 a.m. Est,I was 20 "stars" moving w to e faster than an airliner. They were about 60 degrees off the southern horizon and took several seconds to cross the sky here in central-western pennsylvania. Satellite's? March 1, 2020.

Comment: It may be this: [Line of lights moving in a straight line, with a few following](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32034/7982)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed observation. The most recent Starlink launch was on Feb 17. SpaceX plans to launch thousands of them, and astronomers are unhappy about it.

Comment: Thanks. I had read the post suggested by uhoh, but the time visible  nor comparable speed matched. Otherwise similar. Also the dates of similar queries were all so old.