# Light brightened dimmed disappeared reappeared

Tags: identify-this-object

My son and I saw an unusual light sit in one spot for 15-20 minutes as it got very bright and dimmed, got bright, disappeared and reappeared repeatedly.

It then slowly moved north-west then finally headed west and completely disappeared. it was 45 minutes from the time we first seen it to when it disappeared. I've been searching the web since but couldn't find anything that matches the description of what I saw.

This was March 16th 2020 about 10pm.

Comment: most likely the space station or similar, or several different satellites.  However it isn't a strictly astronomical body, since nothing outside of Earths orbit will ever be observed to "move"

Comment: It may have been a police helicopter. They have very bright searchlights.

Comment: Could you also specify your position at the time you noticed this "unusual light"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line of lights moving in a straight line, with a few following](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following)