# Can any satellite train still be seen?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I "missed the train" on the Starlink satellites last year, and now it looks like they've [separated](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following/32039#32039), and the conservative voices convinced Space X to darken new ones with visors or paint.

Is it still possible to see 2 or more satellites moving in the same direction with the naked eye? (Actually, any celestial bodies visibly moving in the same direction will do.)

I'm located in California and I tried [Find Starlink](https://findstarlink.com/) and the Heavens Above app but wasn't able to see anything.

Comment: You should use the heavens-above.com website and the "Starlink - dynamic 3D orbit display". You can see which launches still have satellites in close proximity. Also, "darken" is a relative term. I believe the satellites will still be visible to the naked eye, especially after launch when they are close to each other and at a lower altitude. Since there are many more launches to go, you will have more opportunities in the near future.

Comment: @JohnHoltz: that visualization is dope! I'm unclear how "far" in space one can see the sats, give the Earth's curvature and their 550km altitude. If I rotate that globe [just right](https://imgur.com/a/Q5D5kxs), it seems that "dandv" observer could see some part of the train... 5 to 10 sats?

Comment: These are different but related questions in Space Exploration SE: [Are there any related groups of satellites that are in a line of 6 or more in a row?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41770/12102) and [Have astronauts seen Starlink trains?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43933/12102)

Answer (score 2):

I can personally attest that the Starlink satellites are visible with the naked eye even after they have spread out, however they are quite dim - with apparent magnitudes near 5.5. Here is a brightness comparison drawn from a widefield capture where two Starlink satellites are can be seen (albeit barely) juxtaposed with another satellite with apparent magnitude near 3.

[image]

The region in which this was taken is Class 1 on the [Bortle Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale) and the entire 60-satellite train was visible, though only 4-5 were visible at any given time. In brighter regions the satellites would not be as readily visible. Furthermore, since they have such low orbits, they were only visible for ~105 degrees in the sky before they passed into Earth's shadow.