# I witnessed a steady stream of falling stars slowly falling one after another this morning. What was it?

Tags: comets, meteor-shower

This morning at 6:18am I witnessed a steady stream of falling stars that lasted at least 90 seconds from the time I noticed it. I live on a farm east of Edmonton, Alberta, Canada and the stars were falling from the south to the east and fading as they neared the tree tops. They fell at 70 degrees east. Any idea what it is I witnessed?

Comment: Does [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following) answer your question?

Comment: @JamesK I've just asked [Are there Starlink train-finding websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48032/12102) in Space SE.

Comment: @EvelynSpooner I've never seen a Starlink "train" but it sure sounds like you have. I asked the question linked in my previous comment in order to find websites where we can check to see if you saw one, though it sure sounds like you did. Hopefully those websites (once there are answers) will also predict future sightings as well. Once the roughly 60 satellites are released from the rocket, they circle the Earth together and slowly drift away from each other, so after each launch there are a few days or weeks when the latest "train" can be seen if one happens to be in the right place.