# Moving stars in the sky

Tags: star, identify-this-object

Today at 7:24 pm, I saw to stars moving parallel to each other for a few seconds in the sky. Then, both suddenly vanished. What phenomenon is this?

Answer (score 3):

Generally bright points of light moving across the sky at a constant speed are satellites. Meteors are much faster and usually have a trail.

If you saw two or more close together and moving at the same speed they were probably some of the [Starlink satellites](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32034/43) launched by SpaceX.

The sudden vanishing is usually because they either moved into Earth's shadow, or the angle of the reflecting surfaces moved so that they didn't reflect light to you as an observer.

Comment: https://heavens-above.com/skyview/?lat=0&lng=0&cul=en#/livesky has a nice updating view of the satellites at the current time (make sure to set your location). It has other pages to lookup what the sky looked like at specific times and we did successfully lookup the first satellite we saw :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt - for Starlink I use findstarlink.com - it seems to be more accurate with visibility ratings