# Football field size object

Tags: orbit

The other night on my bike ride I had an object coming at me - I thought is was a flock of geese (at night -9pm cst) coming at me!
It stayed in a straight line -never vered!
Crossed over me - there were , Id say, 50 plus lights in a row.
I could not see a  body/hull?  No sound  I could not judge how high or low it was above me!
As it passed it disappeared light by light
It was traveling South to North at a slow enough speed for me to film!
Please explain to me what it cold have been, please
There are military bases around, but I've never heard of a craft like this...hmmm
Thanks, Faith - Marble Falls, TX

Comment: It was slightly higher than an aircraft ;-). Sounds like a recently launched group of Starlink satellites. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following and heavens-above.com to confirm the sighting.

Comment: Around 8:05pm local time, a recently launched bunch of Starlink sattelites flew over Texas. Is this time plausible?