Multiple moving lights in the sky, what could it be?
I saw multiple lights in the sky about 30 minutes ago moving on a straight path,the distance from each isn't that much. I counted 18.
Please what could this be?

This was a starlink chain of satellites  See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following  (this should be marked as a duplicate, but I can't do that for you right now.)
